# Is there any utility like `Proxifier` for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, proxy

I'm looking for a program which acts as a proxy manager for Ubuntu just as [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) does for windows.

Comment: Could you add some words what you especially like on Proxifier? This would make it easier to recommend a special software for you.

Comment: I like the feature that allows to easily funnel all the traffic through a specified proxy, system wide. It also allow setting proxy rules.

Comment: I installed Privoxy in Ubuntu but I don't know how to configure it? Exactly, I have a VPN account which perfectly works in Proxifier (Windows). It has a "host name", "user name" and "password". How can I set these parameters in Privoxy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the description of the homepage of Proxifier, the software [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) looks like a good recommendation. Privoxy is a proxy application which filters a lot privacy related things (cookies, webbugs etc.). However the software allows you to configure HTTP, SOCKS and other types of software and is very flexible. I am sure that this is a good replacement.

After reading [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117967/is-there-any-utility-for-ubuntu-like-proxifier-for-windows#comment140340_117967) I can go  a bit more into detail:
The central configuration file is `/etc/privoxy/config`. The directory `/etc/privoxy` has some other files, too. The `config` file is very well documented.

Lets assume you want to send all traffic to example.com though proxy-a and all traffic to askubuntu.com through proxy-b. SSL/TLS traffic (HTTPS) should not use any proxy. So you add the following lines:

```
forward .example.com proxy-a
forward .askubuntu.com proxy-b
forward :443 .
```

The keyword `forward` is followed by a site or a pattern. It can be an IP address, hostname or a regular expression. All traffic which matches will be send to the last entry in the line. This the proxy address. When you use a `.` (a dot) a the end of a line, it means that the pattern before will not use any proxy. You will find more information at the [handbook](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#FORWARD).

Comment: can be more specific for an https server ip with username and password? I tried Proxychains, it works good but unsuccessful in opening Facebook against Proxifier.

Answer (score 3):

I know its a very old question. But i'll answer it for anyone that is still looking for a good "Proxifer" alternative.

Redsocks seems to do a good job!.

http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/

I set it up to route to multiple socks proxies. Example config from `/etc/redsocks.conf` below:

```
redsocks {
local_ip = 127.0.0.1; ip = 127.0.0.1; type = socks5;
local_port = 11081;
port = 1081;
}
redsocks {
local_ip = 127.0.0.1; ip = 127.0.0.1; type = socks5;
local_port = 11082;
port = 1082;
}
```

Then setup iptables to route to the different ports

```
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.220.0/23 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 11082

iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.234.0/23 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 11081

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --uid-owner luser -j REDSOCKS
```

Answer (score 3):

## Proxifier for linux:

As of 2019 there is no bundled application that does all what proxifier does instead you can use different applications for each proxifier feature.

- **Block network for an application**

  [Here is](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454767/120919) a detailed list of solutions for this purpose
- **Route by ip**

  Linux [routing table](http://linux-ip.net/linux-ip/routing-tables.html) can be used to add rules to the routing table and thus route ip/ip-range
- **Route by domain**

  A combination of a sniproxy plus a dns server can do the job (this also support socks and can be be setup easily) [SNI-SSL-Proxy](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/SNI-SSL-Proxy) and [Unbound](https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/) ([on github](https://github.com/NLnetLabs/unbound))
- **Route by application (proxy)**

  [Proxybound](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Proxy/Proxybound) can do the job
- **Route by application (interfaces)**

  [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498140/120919) enumerate the different solutions for that purpose.
- **Watch and monitor network traffic**

  [Network-Watcher](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Network-Watcher) or [Watcher-TCP-View](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-Network/Network-Watcher-TCP-View) will do the job

Answer (score 2):

you can use `tsocks` or `dante`